# ssh: connect to host "raspberry pi IP address" port 22: Operation timed out

Tags: ssh, connection

I have seen this question in multiple places while I searched on Google, but none gave an answer on how to bypass this issue, and I think it will help me and many others to finally know the answer. My problem is that when I try to connect my raspberry pi to my mac book pro I use X11, and here is the prompt:

```
bash-3.2$ ssh-keygen -R "raspberry pi IP address"
```

Then it accepts it in the directory, so then I enter:

```
bash-3.2$ ssh -X "raspberry pi username"@"raspberry pi IP address"
```

And then I receive the error:

```
ssh: connect to host "raspberry pi IP address" port 22: Operation timed out
```

I would like to know can possibly be the cause for this issue and how I can fix it?

Comment: Your question is too vague. Forget `ssh-keygen` until you get past the basics. Don't be so coy about what you actually typed - it isn't secret.  Don't use "-X" Follow https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/ssh/README.md then see how you go.

Comment: Did you enable ssh via **raspi-config**?